# Transfer ETH and tokens to remote geth account not working

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I have a remote geth node I stood up and pointed to Ropsten launched at command line by using:

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

I then checked that i had accounts, which I did. I copied the address to my meta mask wallet that was also pointed to the Ropsten network. I sent 1 ETH to my account generated on my geth node and the ETH never arrived.
Ropsten block explorer states it did https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe1a3e0dc106a2cefe7a90bc7cadaf43e6c8c15e5a7a4b1e8dd02dc171c674859

When I check my balance using:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x54a25257aa677e944403a33974e296b11997a919", "latest"],"id":1}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

I get:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0"}
```

What am I doing wrong? and is the transfer and check for balance the same for tokens?

Comment: What does `eth.getBlock("latest").number` return?

Comment: It returns 0. Does that mean something is wrong with the flags I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `eth.getBlock("latest").number` returns 0, that means your client has not finished syncing.

This is also why your balance query is returning 0, because it has not caught up yet!

Comment: well thats good news then. how long does a fast sync take its been syncing for 4 hours now. Thanks for the help BTW